# How to merge two lucene indexes horizontally, say one having 2 fields and another one having 3 fields

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any way to merge two lucene(solr) indexes horizontally?
Few fields in my index need regular re index while others not so much.
I want to index these fields separately and merge in the last.
So if index one has 2 fields and index two has 3 fields. Final merged index will have 5 fields.

Comment: A better approach to create a separate index which will have data from both the index and then delete the 2 indexes

Comment: Probably I couldn't specify the problem clearly. I have 50+ fields in my solr index. Few fields are parent fields of other fields. Earlier we had decided to keep everything flat and duplicated the parent fields with child fields. Now we have run into a problem. If we need to change a parent field we have to reindex every document containing that field. So that's why I want to  index these parent fields  and child fields separately and then merge to speed up whole indexing.